# select all links on page and save into text file using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to select all links (I want to save `href` of `a` tags into file) then save into a text file :

```
$('a.show').each(
  function(){
    //save into text file
    // file=$(this).attr('href'); // something like this
  }
);
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Refer [How to save file using js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405129/javascript-create-and-save-file)

Comment: Is .show class comman to all a

Comment: @Somnath yes all a have same class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a list of all `href` values on a page like so:

```
var urls = $('a').map(function() { return this.href; }).toArray().join(',');
```

However, JavaScript in a browser normally doesn't have permission to access the file system. You may post the values to a server, and perform the write operation from there.